# Updating Context Value from SharePoint List Value in OnVisible in PowerApps form

Tags: sharepoint-online

I currently have a few datacards on my PowerApps View and Edit forms that hide if a value on SharePoint is edited on the form. When the `EscalateS2` field on SharePoint is changed to YES (Control is a Toggle on the form and the SharePoint List field is a YES/NO type.  I have been controlling this with the context of `"s2Visible"`

The toggle is set to OnCheck run:
`UpdateContext({s2Visible: true})`
and OnUncheck it runs: `UpdateContext({s2Visible: false})`

However I've not been able to figure out how to make it check the field when the form is loaded from scratch so it only retains from previous sessions causing UI issues.

I had tried added the following to the Screen's "OnVisible" properties to try and update the Context instantly on load with the following code.

```
If('SHAREPOINTLIST'.EscalateS2="Yes",UpdateContext({s2Visible: true}),UpdateContext({s2Visible: false}))
```

However this fails with a "Invalid Argument Type" error message, so I think I'm either missing something in the code or I am trying this in the wrong part of of the Screen Properties?

Comment: I've also checked if `EscalateS2="Yes"` should be in Boolean format and have tried `EscalateS2="true"` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Instead of quoting the name of the connected SharePoint list, I needed to use `SharePointIntegration.Selected`

So the final code placed in the OnVisible properties of the screen was:

`If(SharePointIntegration.Selected.EscalateS2=true,UpdateContext({s2Visible: true}),UpdateContext({s2Visible: false}))`